# Reading from txt file into array of struct

Tags: c, struct, fgets

```
struct Total
{
    char Name[40];
    int No[40];

};
struct Total *List = NULL;
```

So let's say my content of txt is `"Test;12345"` I want to store `Test` into Name and `12345` into No.

```
fscanf(fptr, "%[^;], %d", List [0].Name, List [0].No);
```

I did it this way, it reads the first line correctly but for some reason it doesn't read the number.

Comment: `"%[^;], %d"` -> `"%[^;];%d"`

Comment: do you know how to use scanf?

Comment: @Jabberwocky still doesn't work

Comment: @user253751 yes why

Comment: do you know that you need to use `&` with scanf?

Comment: @user253751 yeah I tried with and without & still same

Comment: OT: what is the struct supposed to represent? It's strange to have a Name up to 40 characters (NUL terminator included) an an array of also 40 `int`s.

Comment: @TomKarzes oh, you're right, comment deleted. But the format string I suggested should work.

Comment: @Carl [This](https://www.ideone.com/8j2uCJ) works.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes no idea why I made the no as array, that was the problem now it works. Thanks

Comment: as it is now, there is no memory allocated for the `struct Total`